# How to fit elements at slider container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work with statick creation elements, and for this i need to have slider.

I just create slider, but elements are not fit in to slider container.

Example:

```js
var htmlElements;
var userName = "Jonny Programmer"
var id = "6656"

function createUserCard() {
    htmlElements = `<div class="user-card">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu" class="userImage" />
    <div class="info">
        <div class="name">${userName}</div>
        <div class="handle">
            <div class="idPersone">${id}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

    $('.cardsCreation').append(htmlElements);
}

$('#plus-button').on('click', function () {
    createUserCard();
});

(function () {
    var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.image'),
        arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#left-arrow'),
        arrowRight = document.querySelector('#right-arrow'),
        currentImg = 0;

    function initSlider() {
        resetSlider();

        sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
    }

    function resetSlider() {
        for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
            sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function toLeft() {
        resetSlider();
        sliderImages[currentImg - 1].style.display = 'block';
        currentImg--;
    }

    function toRight() {
        resetSlider();
        sliderImages[currentImg + 1].style.display = 'block';
        currentImg++;
    }

    arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (currentImg === 0) {
            currentImg = sliderImages.length;
        }

        toLeft();
    });

    arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (currentImg === sliderImages.length - 1) {
            currentImg = -1;
        }

        toRight();
    });

    initSlider();
})();
```

```css
.user-card, userImage {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.user-card {
    margin: 12px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.userImage {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    border: 5px solid #eee;
}

.name {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.progress {
    color: #25af53;
    font-size: 48px;
}

#plus-button {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #428bca;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #666;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.plus {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 300;
}

#plus-button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 14px 0 #666;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 160px;
}

#left-arrow {
    border-width: 50px 40px 50px 0;
    border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#right-arrow {
    border-width: 50px 0 50px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.vertical-align-wrapper {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

    .vertical-align-wrapper span {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 5rem;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    .vertical-align-wrapper span {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    #left-arrow {
        border-width: 30px 20px 30px 0;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #right-arrow {
        border-width: 30px 0 30px 20px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .arrow {
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="left-arrow" class="arrow"></div>
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="image image-one">
            <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">

                <div class="cardsCreation"></div>

                <button id="plus-button">
                    <p class="plus">+</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image image-two">
            <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
                <span>Slide 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image image-three">
            <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
                <span>Slide 3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-arrow" class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

So as u can see affter tapping **"+"** i add new ellement in to html.

And from two sides i have arrows which are changing slider.

After tapping arrows go down, and this is not good.

And after i will reach limit of adding element in one slider it's add new element to new slider page.

What i want ex:

[image]

Comment: What are the arrows for if you create a second row to add items under the first row? You want multiple sliders with different elements in them?

Comment: @Will if i have at page more 18 elements, this boxes will creating at new slider page

Comment: If you want one slider, and the arrow would slide the elements within it, you need to add overflow:hidden to the wrapper, and nowrap to your slider. But I'm not exactly sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: So that slider doesn't actualy "slide" the elements whitin it, correct? You want to add elements, the number of rows doesn't matter and would be determined by the size of the screen. But if 18 elements are created, it generates another slider "underneath" and the arrow would switch from the new slider, and the "already full of 18 elements" initial slider?

Comment: @Will yes is correct

Comment: The arrows go down because you set top:50%, so when you add elements, the height increases, and so does 50% of the total height

Comment: @Will i put element creation outside **<div class="vertical-align-wrapper">** and arrows stay in one place

Comment: Or simply set top with a fixed number like "40px"

Comment: On a UX standpoint though, I would say that what you're trying to do seems unnatural and not exactly easy to understand for a random user

Answer (score 0):

If you are using toggle of `display` CSS property that happened because it remove whole element from the DOM so, I suggest you to use `visibility or opacity` properties to done your task.